# Ajax Lazyload not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, lazy-loading

I have been trying to get an infinte scroll working in wordpress for about a week now, I have tryed verious diffrent plugins and diffrent coding laguages and I have been struggeling to get them to work. I am not very confident with Javascript JQuery or PHP these are all new to me.

I found a very good blog post and have followed the steps, http://www.affariproject.com/2015/03/ajax-lazyload-wordpress-pagination/, this is the closest I have come to getting it working. All of my posts showing and so is my ajax loader gif however the infinte scroll is still not working :(.

If any one has any ideas of what I am doing wrong it would be much appreciated. I will post the code below, I am unable to give you a link to the wordpress website as it on the loacl server at work. 
Thank you :)

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Blog</h1>
        <div id="lazyload" class="grid_12">
            <?php
              $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
              $query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'paged' => $paged
              );
            ?>
              <?php if (have_posts()) { ?>
                <div class="page" id="p<?php echo $paged; ?>">
                <?php while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
                  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('entry') ?>>
                    <header class="entryheader">
                      <h2 class="entrytitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="entrycontent">
                      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div id="spinner">
              <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </div>
            <script>
              jQuery(function(){
                var page = 2;
                var loadmore = 'on';
                jQuery(document).on('scroll resize', function() {
                  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 60 > jQuery(document).height()) {
                    if (loadmore == 'on') {
                      loadmore = 'off';
                      jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
                      jQuery('#lazyload').append(jQuery('<div class="page" id="p' + page + '">').load('/?paged=' + page + ' .page > *', function() {
                        page++;
                        loadmore = 'on';
                        jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                      }));
                    }
                  }
                });
                jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, options ) {
                  if (xhr.responseText.indexOf('class="page"') == -1) {
                    loadmore = 'off';
                  }
                });
              });
            </script>
</div>
```

Comment: It may be something goes wrong on this `.load('/?paged=' + page + ' .page > *'` line are you missing url might be put a debugger and see what's happening and check your browser console if any errors found there

Comment: Debug the code systematically by commenting pieces of code. You will find the error eventually.

Comment: I have added in my URL to the first blog page and the second page and im still having the same problem. I had a look in my browser console and there are no errors there.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, I have not been able to resolve this issue, however, I have found a plugin that is working and easy to use. It's called YITH Plugin and you can download it through Wordpress plugins, https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-infinite-scrolling/. Thank you to everyone that replied to this post!